# Find sigtrap function

Tags: linux, anti-debugging

I'm reversing a program that uses a lot of `BREAK`/`int 3` (Linux). I guess that the code contains something like:

```
void sigtrap_func(int sig) { (some stuff..) }

int main()
{
  signal(SIGTRAP, sigtrap_func);
  (some stuff)
  asm("int 3");
  (and so on)
  asm("int 3");

etc..
```

I replaced all `SIGTRAP` by `NOP`s and the program behave differently than with them. So, I'm sure that something is done inside the `sigtrap` function.

How can I find this function just with the assembler ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's where strace comes in handy. If i make your program compilable and compile it:

```
$cat trap.c
#include <signal.h>
void sigtrap_func(int sig) { puts("trap"); }

int main()
{
  signal(SIGTRAP, sigtrap_func);
}
$ cc -o trap trap.c
```

and then run it with `strace`, i'll get a list of all system calls the program executes:

```
$strace -i ./trap 
[      31076ad057] execve("./trap", ["./trap"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
... stuff omitted that loads dynamic libraries
[      3107632abe] rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, {0x400504, [TRAP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x31076329a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
[      31076ad038] exit_group(0)        = ?
```

You see that `rt_sigaction` (the system call that implements `signal()`) gets called at `0x3107632abe`, and sets the handler function to `0x31076329a0`. Now is the time to start `gdb`, and set breakpoints there (beware of ASLR though!).

Answer (score 1):

Just like in your sample program, the signal handlers are installed using a `signal` (or `sigaction`) function. So you just need to find the call to that function and see what argument is passed to it. That argument will be the address of the signal handler.